# Combine columns in one file by matching header

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm looking to take one file that has multiple lines and many columns, add (sum) the values horizontally of columns with headers that match. In my file, (not this example) I'm ignoring the first 9 columns and the first row because I want them to be printed in the outcome, untouched.

The columns are not in a repeating order and there are many more columns than the example.

The idea is something like this:

Input:

```
var x y x y x y
a 1 0 1 1 0 1
b 1 1 0 0 1 1
c 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Output:

```
var x y
a 2 2
b 2 2
c 1 1
```

Here's what I've got so far....

```
awk -F '\t' '{FS==OFS} FNR==1; FNR>1 {for (i=10; i<=NF; i++) {} print}' FILE.tsv > FILE_norepcols.tsv
```

Also, if possible I'm trying to understand how to write this code better so please suggest anything that I can/should change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -lane '$,="\t";
   print(qw/var x y/),next if $. == 1;
   push @A, shift @F;
   $A[$|--+1] += $_ for @F;
   print splice @A;
' file
```

**Results:**

```
var x   y
a   2   2
b   2   2
c   1   1
```

***Assumption(s):***

- The number of fields is odd.
- Field#2 onwards are numeric.

**Explanation(*brief*):**

- Header is explicitly printed as shown by the OP.
- Array `@A` is freshly populated for each line by emptying it at the time of printing it by means of the `splice` function.
- Array `@F` stores the fields of the input record `$_`, zero indexed.
- First element (rather the zeroth element) of array `@A` is shifted out from the front of the array `@F`. Note the array `@F` is generated by `perl` each time a new record is read in. This is akin to the `$1, $2, $3, ..., $NF` fields in `awk`.
- The rest of the array `@A` is a binary `(0|1)+1=>(1|2)` element index which accumulate the respective sums from the array `@F`.

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using fairly wordy variable names and intermediate variables to help you understand what's going on (rather than commenting every line or adding an explanation later):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==1 {
    for (inFldNr=2; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        fldName = $inFldNr
        if ( !(fldName in fldName2outFldNr) ) {
            outFldNr2name[++numOutFlds] = fldName
            fldName2outFldNr[fldName] = numOutFlds
        }
        outFldNr = fldName2outFldNr[fldName]
        out2inFldNrs[outFldNr,++numInFlds[outFldNr]] = inFldNr
    }

    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        outFldName = outFldNr2name[outFldNr]
        printf "%s%s", outFldName, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    next
}
{
    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        sum = 0
        for (inFldIdx=1; inFldIdx<=numInFlds[outFldNr]; inFldIdx++) {
            inFldNr = out2inFldNrs[outFldNr,inFldIdx]
            sum += $inFldNr
        }
        printf "%s%s", sum, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
var     x       y
a       2       2
b       2       2
c       1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```
<file datamash -W transpose | 
  datamash -W --headers -s -g1 sum 2-4 |
  datamash --output-delimiter=' ' transpose
```

- Transpose the file using whitespace as delimiter (`-W`)
- Group on the first field (`-g1`), sort before grouping (`-s`) and sum the values on fields 2-4. The first input line is treated as column header and printed in the output (`--headers`)
- Transpose the result and use a space character as delimiter instead of a tab.

Output:

```
GroupBy(var) x y
sum(a) 2 2
sum(b) 2 2
sum(c) 1 1
```

---

Pretty-print the result with `sed`:

```
<file datamash -W transpose | 
  datamash -W --headers -s -g1 sum 2-4 |
  datamash --output-delimiter=' ' transpose | 
  sed 's/^[^(]*(\([^)]*\))/\1/'
```

Output:

```
var x y
a 2 2
b 2 2
c 1 1
```

---

You could use `cut` to remove the first nine columns from your input file and add them back to the result with `paste`:

```
paste -d ' ' <(cut -d' ' -f-9 file) <(cut -d' ' -f10- file | datamash ... )
```

An additional header line could be printed with `head -n1` and skipped with `tail -n+2`:

```
{
  head -n1 file 
  paste -d ' ' <(tail -n+2 file | cut -d' ' -f-9) <(tail -n+2 file | cut -d' ' -f10- | datamash ... )
}
```